# Visual Studio Xampp data connection

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, xampp

I want to add a data connection in Visual Studio 2013. I want to use Xampp for hosting my database on localhost. I seted up my database with phpmyadmin. Now i want to add a connection in VS.

Under server explorer i choose add new data connection. I choose the micorosoft odbc data structure. Next i wanted to build a new connection string. But i cannot find a Mysql odbc driver for that.
So i downloaded it directly from mysql http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ and installed it. I tried to restart my computer and VS but this driver still doesnt appear.

Comment: You want mysqlconnector, not odbc

Comment: there is no option for mysql when i want to add a new data connection. Just microsoft, oracle and other options. Under other options there are also no mysql options.

Comment: One thing is not the other. Download this, read the instrictions on how to use it. http://download.cnet.com/MySQL-Connector-NET/3000-10254_4-75914773.html

Comment: Do I realy need that connector or can i connect using the mysql.data & msql.web dlls and hardcode a connection string? Is that way also common? Thanks

Comment: No idea, I never ever ever go near ODBC, unless there's absolutely no alternative whatsoever. Not mad keen on hardcoding connection strings either, not anything else for that matter.

Comment: OK Tony, how would you do it?

Comment: install mysql connector! VS will see it and give you the option of seeting a connection string to a mysql db....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded and installed this MySQL For Visual Studio first
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/
then the connector
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

I have no problem connecting to MySQL. Make sure XAMPP MySQL running though when you trying to connect.

PS. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and latest XAMPP. I have only installed MySQL Workbench and nothing else.